# MUI hideBackDrop={true} doesnt allow me to click outside of Drawer component to close it

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, mui-datatable, mui-x

I have a Drawer component that opens when I click an icon on the Map. Then the drawer menu opens and the backshadow drops on the map. When i click on the map with backshadow the drawer simply closes without problem. I want to remove the backshadow tho, so in the API it says i can just use hideBackDrop={true}, this does indeed remove the backshadow but if i click on the outside of drawer on the map now it doesnt close drawer.

```
<SwipeableDrawer
  disableEnforceFocus={disableAutoFocus}
  disableAutoFocus={disableAutoFocus}
  anchor="bottom"
  open={isOpen}
  onClose={onClose}
  onOpen={onOpen}
  hideBackdrop={hideBackdrop}
>
  <Box role="presentation">{children}</Box>
</SwipeableDrawer>
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?